# Programmatically set the Keyboard.Modifiers (WPF)

Tags: wpf

Has anybody found a way to set the Keyboard.Modifiers via code in WPF?  Only a getter is exposed, so there must be some other way to do it that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The Keyboard.Modifiers are only intended for reading input, hence there only being a getter. You can't tell the keyboard what keys are pressed!

Comment: Basically, I need to build up my own KeyPress event and have it processed, but if you programatically build a KeyPress event, you can't say "Press Ctrl D", you can only say "Press D"