# How do I simulate Ctrl-S key combination?

Tags: .net, wpf

How to simulate single key press is described here

[How can I programmatically generate keypress events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c)

But how can I simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> combination?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278347/programatically-set-the-keyboard-modifiers-wpf

Comment: Can you clarify for me, which answers don't work and why in your linked question?

Comment: The accepted answer work only for a single key press. I need to detect key combination (Ctrl and S).

Comment: 1st you say you need to simulate it, then you say you need to detect it.  which one, or both?

Comment: sorry. i need only to simulate it, not detect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library on CodePlex allows you to simulate multiple keystrokes
[Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);
```